# How to remove a special category from wp_list_categories result

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use blow code instead of my menu

```
<?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&depth=4&orderby=id'); ?>
```

I want to remove a special category from wp_list_categories result. I use that category for an other work apart from menu bar.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `exclude` parameter.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Include_or_Exclude_Categories

```
<?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&depth=4&orderby=id&exclude=cat_id'); ?>
```

Replace `cat_id` with the ID of the category you wish to exclude. If there's more than one, separate each ID with a comma.

Comment: Can I use cat_name instead of cat_id

Comment: @Ehsan To my knowledge, the `exclude` parameter only accepts category id.